# how to get Graphics HW to work? using Multipass with XRDP. the remote desktop GUI is laggy

Tags: drivers, graphics, xrdp

we are using Multipass with XRDP. the remote desktop GUI is laggy

I think this is root cause -- the VM doesnt see the graphics HW or doesnt have the right graphics driver turned on

bare metal - canonical 20.04

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)

Multipass VM - canonical 20.04

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111 (rev 02)